# What are those white things in my juice & can it cause me any harm?

Tags: nutrition, food-safety

So i got this white weird condensed things into my juice once i added some milk into it & i got worried whether it is a normal thing or can it have some risk on my health ! Is this a safe juice & what can cause this?

[image: this is a picture of it]

Comment: Did you take the fruits and make the juice or is it from juice boxes?

Comment: Its from the juice box.

Comment: Juice boxes are not healthy at all. You should eat the whole fruit if you are seeking to be healthier. There are fruit preservatives in the juice. Font: Dr. Lair Ribeiro

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is clearly off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fruit juice is acidic, and [acid makes milk curdle](http://www.thekitchn.com/food-science-why-lemon-makes-m-88057). This is the end result. It's harmless. It's pretty much just juice-flavored cottage cheese.